# Move Photos from iPhone to iPad

Tags: itunes, applescript, photos

I have to help someone do this, so I do not have the devices in front of me to play around with.

There are three devices involved:

1. Macbook (don't know what model)
2. iPhone (don't know what model)
3. iPad (don't know what model)

The objective is to move some photos from the iPhone to the iPad.

What is the most straightforward way to accomplish this using iTunes?

Also, if there are any AppleScript hackers out there with experience in iTunes, a stub of an AppleScript to perform this task would be really helpful!

FYI, in my case using the internet is not really an option, so iCloud and the like are out.

Comment: I personally don't think Apple has done that great with this process. For those who can access the internet, Photostream is reasonable, but I think it has a few shortcomings. The answer below is probably the best way. It doesn't take long either. I use iPhoto which essentially does the same, while managing the library on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **Image Capture** to import the pictures to your computer.
2. In iTunes, connect and select your device, then in the Photos tab select the folder that you put the photos when you imported them.
3. Press Sync.

Once you've done this once, it become easier. You already have the folder set up in Image Capture and in iTunes, so all you have to do is…

1. Connect your iPhone (you can set up Image Capture to open automatically when you connect your iPhone in System Preferences).
2. Click Import.
3. Connect your iPad and click Sync.

---

Alternatively, you could purchase an iPad Camera Connection Kit, then use a USB cable to connect the iPhone directly to your iPad and use your iPad to import the photos.